# merge 2 fb api calls

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to merge two api calls to the facebook javascript sdk:

```
FB.api('/me?fields=name,first_name,gender', callback1);
FB.api('me/photos?type=uploaded&fields=tags,likes', {limit: 120}, callback2);
```

I want to make just one api call but how to get all the information with just one api call?

Answer (score 0):

The keyword is "Batch Requests": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests

...although, those would still be 2 different API calls then, just faster. Another solution:

```
/me?fields=name,photos{tags,likes}
```

Not sure if it´s possible to only get the uploaded ones that way though. I would prefer Batch Requests, because they are more flexible.